Existence of covering $X_1 \rightarrow X_2$ if $\mathrm{Aut}_{q_1} \subset \mathrm{Aut}_{q_2}$.
Suppose $q_1: E \rightarrow X_1$ and $q_2: E \rightarrow X_2$ are normal coverings. Show that there exists a covering $X_1 \rightarrow X_2$ making the obvious diagram commute if and only if $\mathrm{Aut}_{q_1} \subset \mathrm{Aut}_{q_2}$.
The only if part is easy. I'm stuck with the if part. If I can somehow show $\mathrm{Aut}_{q_1}$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}_{q_2}$, I know how to proceed.

Let me simplify the notation by using $\Gamma_i = \text{Aut}_{q_i}$. This group $\Gamma_i$ acts on the space $E$ as the deck transformation group of $q_i$. The orbits of the action of $\Gamma_i$ on $E$ are precisely those subsets of the form $q_i^{-1}(x_i)$ as $x_i \in X_i$ varies. For $p \in E$ let me use $[p]_i$ as the $\Gamma_i$ orbit of $p$. It follows for each $p,p' \in E$ that $q_i(p)=q_i(p')$ if and only if $[p]_i=[p']_i$.
From your hypothesis that $\Gamma_1 \subset \Gamma_2$, it follows that $[p]_1 \subset [p]_2$ for each $p \in E$.
I can now use this fact to write down a formula for a function $f : X_1 \to X_2$, namely
$$f(x_1) = q_2(p) \quad\text{for any $p \in q_1^{-1}(x_1)$}
$$
This is guaranteed to be a well-defined value in $X_2$: for any $p,p' \in q_1^{-1}(x_1)$ we have $[p]_1=[p']_1$. The orbits $[p]_2$ and $[p'_2]$ therefore have nonempty intersection. But the orbits of $\Gamma_2$ form a decomposition of $E$ and so $[p]_2=[p']_2$. It follows that $q_2(p)=q_2(p')$.
The map $f$ obviously make the obvious diagram commute.

To prove $f$ is a covering map, it suffices to prove that for any open subset $U \subset X_2$ that is evenly covered by $q_2$, that set $U$ is also evenly covered by $f$.
You say you know what to do if $\Gamma_1 = \text{Aut}_{q_1}$ is normal in $\Gamma_2 = \text{Aut}_{q_2}$. If it's not normal, the idea of the proof is to take advantage of the right cosets of $\Gamma_1$ in $\Gamma_2$.
We have an open decomposition
$$q_2^{-1}(U) = \sqcup_i V_i
$$
such that the restriction $q_2 : V_i \to U$ is a homeomorphism  for each $i$.
The group $\Gamma_2$ acts transitively and faithfully on the set $\{V_i\}_i$, and so we can re-index that set by $\Gamma_2$ itself as $\{V_g\}_{g \in \Gamma_2}$, so that $g \cdot V_e = V_g$ (where $e$ is of course the identity). The action of the group $\Gamma_2$ on $E$ restricts to an action of the subgroup $\Gamma_1$ on $E$. For each $g \in \Gamma_2$, the action of $\Gamma_1$ on $E$ induces an action on the subset $\{V_h\}_{h \in \Gamma_1 g}$, which as shown is indexed by the right coset $\Gamma_1g$. It follows that $\bigcup_{h \in \Gamma_1 g} V_h$ is a saturated open subset with respect to the covering map $q_1$. Its image under $q_1$ is therefore an open subset of $X_1$ that I'll denote $W_{\Gamma_1 g}$. Chasing around the diagram, it follows that $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism $f : W_{\Gamma_1 g} \to U$. Furthermore, if we let $g_j$ vary over a set of right coset representatives of $\Gamma_1$ in $\Gamma_2$, it follows that the sets $\{W_{\Gamma_1 g_j}\}$ are pairwise disjoint and their union is all of $f^{-1}(U)$. This proves that $f$ evenly covers $U$.

I understand $f$ is a well-defined quotient map. That's actually the easy part. The difficulty lies exactly in proving that for every point $x_2 \in X_2$, there is a neighborhood $V_2$ such that $V_1 \equiv f^{-1}(V_2)$ is a union of components each of which is homeomorphic to $V_2$. If $E$ is a finite covering, it's easy because a finite intersection of open sets is fine. But what if $E$ is an infinite covering of both $X_1$ and $X_2$?

I see, you did not mention in your post that you already knew how to define the function. Well, verifying that it's a covering map is pretty much the same idea using orbits; I can write more later.

Added more to the answer.

Thanks. Somehow I missed the part "saturated" in my original thinking. It's really the key word that I needed. I tried to prove $\Gamma_1$ is normal in $\Gamma_2$ in vain.

Heh, yes. I've always liked the "saturated" idea, it gives me some geometric intuition. Also, one can construct examples of this sort where $\Gamma_2$ is any group and $\Gamma_1$ is any subgroup of $\Gamma_2$. So there's no hope in proving that $\Gamma_1$ is normal in $\Gamma_2$.
